# Sidr Plugin not working for my Wordpress Site

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've recently tried to install the jQuery [Slidr](http://www.berriart.com/sidr/) plugin for my custom wordpress theme but haven't had any luck getting it to work. When I try to call the sidebar to appear by binding it to my '#mobile-menu' anchor tag I get this error in my console, "TypeError: $(...).sidr is not a function".

Here's how my code is laid out:

**functions.php**

```
function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery()
{

wp_register_script( 'init', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascripts/initialize.js' , array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
wp_register_script( 'sidr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascripts/jquery.sidr.min.js' , array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );


wp_enqueue_script( 'init' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'sidr' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );
```

**initialize.js**

```
(function($) {
$('#mobile-menu').sidr();
})(jQuery);
```

Link to my site: http://www.xboxoneachievementguides.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('#mobile-menu').sidr();
    })
```

Please try this, i have checked its running